# Command line length limit: built-in vs executable

Tags: bash, shell, posix, limit

So per [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) we have the following definition for `*`:

> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one, initially
>   producing one field for each positional parameter that is set. When
>   the expansion occurs in a context where field splitting will be
>   performed, any empty fields may be discarded and each of the non-empty
>   fields shall be further split as described in Field Splitting. When
>   the expansion occurs in a context where field splitting will not be
>   performed, the initial fields shall be joined to form a single field
>   with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of
>   the IFS variable if IFS contains at least one character, or separated
>   by a  if IFS is unset, or with no separation if IFS is set to a
>   null string.

For a vast majority of people we are aware of the famous `ARG_MAX` limitation:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2621440
```

which may lead to:

```
$ cat * | sort -u > /tmp/bla.txt
-bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

Thankfully the good people behind `bash` ([include all POSIX-like others]) provided us with `printf` as a built-in, so we can simply:

```
printf '%s\0' * | sort -u --files0-from=- > /tmp/bla.txt
```

And everything is transparent for the user.

Could someone please let me know why this is so trivial to bypass the `ARG_MAX` limitation using a `built-in` command and why it is so damn hard to provide a conforming POSIX shell interpreter which would handle gracefully `*` special parameter to a standalone executable:

```
$ cat *
```

Would that break something ? I am not asking `bash` people to provide `cat` as a built-in, I am solely interested in the order of operations and why is `*` expanded in different behavior depending whether the command is build-in or is a standalone executable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The limitation is not in the shell but in the `exec()` family of functions.

The POSIX standard [says in relation to this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html):

> The number of bytes available for the new process' combined argument and environment lists is `{ARG_MAX}`. It is implementation-defined whether null terminators, pointers, and/or any alignment bytes are included in this total.

To run utilities that are built into the shell, the shell will not need to call `exec()`, so it is unaffected by this limitation.

Notice, too, that it's not simply the length of the command line that is limited, but the combination of the length of the command, its arguments, and the current environment variables and their values.

Also notice that `printf` is *not* a built in utility in e.g. `pdksh` (which happens to act as `sh` and `ksh` on OpenBSD).  Relying on it being a built-in will need to take the specific shell which is being used into account.

Comment: @malat `xargs` is a program which can help you to call a program multiple times with a limited number of arguments. (To solve this `exec()` issue for subprocesses.)

Answer (score 6):

[Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda)’s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365338/86440) explains why `ARG_MAX` isn’t an issue with shell built-ins.

As far as implementing `cat *` in a way that’s not affected by `ARG_MAX`, doing so is trivial: all that the `cat` implementation needs to do is use [`glob(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) to implement its own globbing, and then you’d run it using `cat \*` or `cat '*'` so that the shell doesn’t do its own globbing. You’ll find a few commands on a Linux or Unix-style system which can take care of their own globbing, at least in certain circumstances; `find`, `tar`, `zip` etc. Many commands with native DOS versions would at least include code to handle globbing since the shells there don’t glob external commands’ arguments themselves.

Given POSIX shell expectations, that feature would be rather surprising and hard to discover! In early Unix versions, globbing was implemented using a separate program, `/etc/glob`.

Comment: A famous example of application that does that is the UNIX port of `rar`.  It's the reason why it takes forever for `rar` to start when you run it from a directory containing many files. :)

Comment: @Sato that’s interesting — does it take longer for `rar` to glob than it does the shell, or are its globs more “sophisticated”?

Comment: Unlike normal `glob`, `rar` recursively descends into subdirectories.  Not sure what it's actually trying to achieve by that, but the effect is it's getting too smart for its own good. :)